# Separating different sized blank spaces with awk and adding zeros to a column

Tags: awk

I am having trouble in treating a table that is separated by different sized blank spaces and of different sized elements. Ideally I want all fields separated by a tab. I would also like to add a zero entry to any field elements that are blank. Not sure if awk FS/OFS is the most appropriate way here given that there are different sized blank spaces between fields.

If I do awk '{print $4}' I get a combo of column 4 and column 5 on the entries after 3rd row. So I feel I need a formal separator.

Current code (separator different sized blank spaces):

```
   1         0.98809     1.28484E-01 2.15265E-02 1.0559      1.1562      212.92      1.2248
   2         1.0222      5.81189E-01 1.24861E-04 1.0222      1.2548      216.26      1.8981
   3         1.1162      1.11291E-02             1.1256      1.2642      222.04      4.0946
   4         1.1922      2.0822                  1.1219      1.2826      216.16      4.1229
```

Expected code (separator tab, with zeros added in to fill blanks):

```
   1         0.98809     1.28484E-01 2.15265E-02 1.0559      1.1562      212.92      1.2248
   2         1.0222      5.81189E-01 1.24861E-04 1.0222      1.2548      216.26      1.8981
   3         1.1162      1.11291E-02 0.0         1.1256      1.2642      222.04      4.0946
   4         1.1922      2.0822      0.0         1.1219      1.2826      216.16      4.1229
```

Comment: Is it always going to be 3rd and 4th field where you want to add zeros(Are 3rd and 4th fields always have scientific notation in their values?)? Because measuring spaces in any language is a tough ask, so please confirm once.

Comment: I would go with adding a 4 field if  the count of fields is 8, not 9.

Comment: If you have GNU awk, I think you can use **FIELDWIDTHS** for this.

Comment: You said you wanted as output a table of tab-separated values and then accepted the first answer you got which does NOT output a table of tab separated values and won't fill blank fields with `0.0` as you show. Please fix your question to state your real requirements for the benefit of people with similar needs looking for a solution in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution using GNU awk and its formatting using `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="13 12 12 12 12 12 12 12"; OFS="\t"} 
     {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
          $i=($i+0?$i:sprintf("%-" length($i) "s","0.0"))
     }1' file
```

The script loops through *all* fields (not only the 4th one) to check if empty. If so, a `0.0` padded with spaces is assigned to the empty field.